# Use KeyListener in a loop

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, keylistener

I don't have a lot of experience with KeyListeners but I used one in my application and it works fine except I need to wait for input before my program can continue. For this I made a while loop that loops until the String temp is not null (which would mean there would be input).

The problem is there is no way to type in the JTextField (called input). Below is code from my two methods that are supposed to work together so that the text in my JTextField (input) can be returned (as temp). I'm not sure why this doesn't work or how to fix it.

The keyPressed method for my KeyListener:

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    //only sends text if the enter key is pressed
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
        //if there really is text
        if (!input.getText().equals(""))
        {
            //String temp is changed from null to input
            temp=input.getText();
            //text sent to another JTextField
            output.append(temp+"\n");
            //input no longer has text
            input.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

The method thats trying to get text, also in my KeyListener class

```
public String getTemp()
{
    booleans isNull=temp==null; 
    //loops until temp is not null
    while (isNull)
    {
        //unnecessary line of code, only used so the loop not empty
        isNull=checkTemp();
    }   
    return temp;
}
public boolean checkTemp()
{
    return temp==null;
}
```

Comment: It's using swing

Comment: Why don't you use a dialog to get the user's input? Also, you can just register a listener on your input field.

Comment: It's basically like a chatbot though so I think that would change the feel significantly,

Comment: Get rid of all that code and instead add an ActionListener to the JTextField.

Comment: That's  where the keyListener already is though

Comment: @BenCarlisle: trust me on this -- use an ActionListener. You could give your GUI a submit JButton and have the JTextField and the button share the same listener, and it will work beautifully. Please see example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is a common console program construct, but understand that you're not creating a console program here but rather an **event-driven** GUI, and in this situation, the while loop fights against the Swing GUI library, and you need to get rid of it. Instead of a while loop with continual polling you now want to respond to events, and if you're listening for user input into a JTextField **do not use a KeyListener** as this low-level listener can cause unwanted side effects. Instead add a DocumentListener to the JTextField's Document.

Edit: You're listening for the **enter** key, and so the solution is even easier: add an ActionListener to the JTextField!

e.g.,

```
input.addActionListener(e -> {
    String text = input.getText().trim();
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    output.append(text + "\n");

    input.setText("");
});
```

More complete example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChatBox extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 40;
    private JTextField input = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextArea output = new JTextArea(20, COLS);
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");

    public ChatBox() {
        output.setFocusable(false); // user can't get into output
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        ActionListener inputListener = e -> {
            String text = input.getText().trim();
            if (text.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            output.append(text + "\n");

            input.setText("");
            input.requestFocusInWindow();
        };

        input.addActionListener(inputListener);
        submitButton.addActionListener(inputListener);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(input);
        bottomPanel.add(submitButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ChatBox mainPanel = new ChatBox();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Box");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really in depth answer and I understand why an actionListener is better to use in this situation than a keyListener but in the past hour I havent been able to figure out how to make my code respond to events in the proper way since without the while loop the actonListener isnt considered instead temp is returned as it is (null)

Comment: @BenCarlisle: that while loop shouldn't be in there. Just get rid of it and banish it from your thoughts. Whenever you think to do continuous polling in a GUI using a while loop, try to say to yourself, "how can I do this by listening to events instead?". As for use of a KeyListener, this can mess up the internal workings of a JTextField and other text components and should be avoided. For example they can mess up the tabbing functioning of these components and fail with copy and pasting of text.

Comment: @BenCarlisle: and the getTemp should be called from within the ActionListener or other similar listener. Again, respond to events.